# Separate buttons in UITable without custom cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

Is it possible to have a UITable with cells that are all the same, each containing buttons that only effect that cell (based on indexPath.row I'm guessing), without having to make a custom cell?

Comment: In order to use a button within a tableview cell, you need to create a custom cell. Then you need to create a delegate method within that custom cell class that tells the view controller a button has been clicked in the cell. Let me know if you decide to do this and I will post a code explanation.

Comment: @kaylaGalway so the only way to know which button in which cell has been click is to have a custom cell?

Answer (score 1):

I too need this, but I have a custom cell.

@kaylaGalway your method sounds like it could work for me, could you elaborate? As I have been searching for this answer for hours now (Swift 3)

Answer (score 0):

You can design your table cells freely. It is possible to have a different cell for each and every row within the very same table.

When you have matching cell types for each row you can also add buttons (one or more) in these rows. They can also point to the very same function. With a clever usage of the 'tag' you can identify each individual button. Using the Indexpath.row you can naturally also identify the row in the table.